# Making read-only in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

I need a huge field, where I can both have client write text, aswell as have html elements within.

Imagine a console, if you will - the first line (me@linuxbox:~$) or something like that, being an element that client can't manipulate, and after this element, the client can type whatever they want.

https://jsfiddle.net/a1k2xo0d/1/

```
<div id="container">
<textarea>
<p>me@linuxbox:~$</p>text........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to make a console of some sort.

Try the `<input>` tag with some JS

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhxstst7/)

Comment: Very nice example, but how would I then achieve the text input to fill every line completely in width, break line at end and proceed to prepend further text just below the identifier?

Comment: I would simply append next element and focus it, when you hit enter. Experiment with the code (I guesss you could be doing that just now)

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated fiddle -

1. Use `position:absolute` and adjust `span` on `textarea`
2. Leave that much of `padding-left` on `textarea`

Link - https://jsfiddle.net/rLvr7n3r/1/

Comment: Problem is the line break, doesn't show up inder the string now.. :(

Comment: yes exactly, the ideal would be for the next line to appear below ur the identifier